# How to show a div on hover of icon when there are multiple divs on a single blog page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a main div `slidewrapper` which contains a div mainchImage and another `sliderimage` div ..`Sliderwrapper` div gets appended to all post imagesog wordpress blog ..So the images are dynamically coming and hence the div are static ..No chance of changing the div id ... For more details plz chk this

In this demo on hover of icon only the first slidergallery is shown and not the sildergallery of respective icon

http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/MsFYS/

Comment: Do you want to show the same div on every occasions or is the div depending on the the hovered icon?

Comment: yeah div id is same ..and i want to show besides that resp cliked icon but the content inside tat slider div are dynamically comming...

Answer (score 1):

You have following issues in your code,

1. You cannot have multiple elements with same id
2. image tags should be closed

Since you cannot change the htmls structure, try following code

```
jQuery(".showcatdiv").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).parent().next("div").show();
});

jQuery(".showcatdiv").parent().next("div").mouseout(function () {
    jQuery(this).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MsFYS/1/

***note: this is not the best way of doing this. but since you are having mal html, you have to do something like this.***

Comment: Thanks but only the first part is working ..it is nt hiding when i click on close button div on that div ..

Comment: Where is a close button? i can't see. and where did you mentioned it on the question?

Comment: forgt that close button ... i have used ur mouseout function...But it is stil working on first div only .. chk this link  and here u can c the problem http://santasrecipies.com/